# 2 textbox that copies each other value while typing, but the other textbox has no comma

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently working with 2 `textboxes` that copies each other values. But the thing is, my 1st textbox has an autocomma. How could I make my 2nd textbox ignore the comma?

> For example. My first **textbox value is 1,000** then my **2nd textbox
> value should be 1000**.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="textbox2"/>
```

**Script**

```
//this function is for my autocomma
function updateTextView(_obj){
    var num = getNumber(_obj.val());
        if(num==0){
            _obj.val('');
        }else{
            _obj.val(num.toLocaleString());
        }
    }   
    function getNumber(_str){
        var arr = _str.split('');
        var out = new Array();
        for(var cnt=0;cnt<arr.length;cnt++){
            if(isNaN(arr[cnt])==false){
                out.push(arr[cnt]);
            }
       }
       return Number(out.join(''));
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#textbox1').on('keyup',function(){
            updateTextView($(this));
        });
    });

//this function copies the textbox1 values to textbox value 2
    $("#textbox1").bind('input', function () {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#textbox2").val(stt);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify the function `updateTextView` as below:

```
function updateTextView(_obj) {
   var num = getNumber(_obj.val());
   if (num == 0) {
     _obj.val('');
     $("#textbox2").val('');
   } else {
     $("#textbox2").val(num);
     _obj.val(num.toLocaleString());
   }
}
```

And then remove the following:

```
$("#textbox1").bind('input', function () {
   var stt = $(this).val();
   $("#textbox2").val(stt);
});
```

Comment: I just follow your logic. 8)

Answer (score 1):

In plain JS:

Try the `onkeyup()` event added to the first textbox. Then replace all commas in the value of the first box with nothing using `value.replace(/,/g, "")`. And then copy the value of the first input

```js
function update(input) {
  var value = input.value.replace(/,/g, "");
  document.getElementById("second-textbox").value = value;
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="(update(this))" />
<input id="second-textbox" />
```

to the second.